# laravel id-helpeClass 'App\Models\Eloquent' not found

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

i'm just started to use laravel ide-helper in phpstorm and wanted to document my models.

I've run the command `php artisan ide-helper:models` but comes up with the error:

```
'App\Models\Eloquent' not found
```

After reading it looks as if the error lies in what my models extend - my model class looks like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model { }
```

This is the standard set in the Laravel docs and created by the generators.

Is there a way to resolve this issue so I can generate the docs with the helper or do I leave as is.

Bit confused

Thanks

Comment: Try removing leading backslash from `use` (it's not needed at all) - but probably it won't help.

Comment: HI - yep it didnt make a difference - however I examined the stack further and the error was being thrown for not finding a relationship in the model rather than the model itself which I had assumed! - so solved for now - thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to include Eloquent (without the PATH)

```
use Eloquent;
```